# How do you add a class to a Leaflet marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm using custom divIcons for my Leaflet markers. I want to add a border to whatever marker I click on, with some simple CSS:

```
.selectedMarker {
border: 10px solid gold;
}
```

However, the following with jQuery doesn't work:

```
$(marker).addClass('selectedMarker');
```

Then I tried to use Leaflet's own [addClass() method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domutil-addclass). I tried to call use it in the following ways:

```
marker.addClass('selectedMarker');
L.addClass(marker, 'selectedMarker');
addClass(marker, 'selectedMarker');
DomUtil.addClass(marker, 'selectedMarker');
```

None of these work. How do I add the selectedMarker class to my marker?

Comment: what is the $(marker)?

Comment: jQuery. Which doesn't work, as jQuery targets DOM elements, not JavaScript objects.

Comment: Note you've linked to leaflet docs for `L.DomUtil.addClass()` but your question has `L.addClass()`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have done it by adding a class to the marker with

```
var marker = L.marker(loc);
marker.on('click', function() {
    $(marker._icon).addClass('selectedMarker');
}
```

and then use the css

```
.leaflet-marker-icon.selectedMarker{
  //your css
}
```

Answer (score 29):

In 1.0 and 0.7 you can use [L.DomUtil](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domutil) to add remove classes from a DOM element:

```
L.DomUtil.addClass(marker._icon, 'className');
L.DomUtil.removeClass(marker._icon, 'className');
```

Comment: It's worth mentionting that markers must be added to map. Otherwise `_icon` is `undefined`.

Comment: If using `L.circleMarker` you need to pass `marker._path` instead of `marker._icon`

Comment: is it possible to save the Dom elements when removing the Layer?

Answer (score 20):

without using jQuery,

```
marker._icon.classList.add("className");
```

Comment: Confirmed this works, thanks. This is the best method to do it I think. Unfortunately `classList` remains undefined until the user clicks it, so can't add a class right after creating it with this method. Also, tip for those using leaflet markercluster, it's in `event.layer._icon`.

Comment: I had to do this with polygons. `layer._path.classList.add("className")` worked for me in that case.

Comment: Use `marker._path` for `L.circleMarker` too. Within a click handler you can obtain reference to this from `event.target._path`

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `marker = new Marker()` syntax, and then `marker._icon` doesn't work. What solved this for me was to just set a new icon initialized with another class, like so

```
const originalIcon = new Icon({
    iconUrl: iconImg,
    iconSize: [50, 50],
});
const iconWithNewClass = new Icon({
    iconUrl: iconImg,
    iconSize: [50, 50],
    className: 'new-class',
});

...

marker.setIcon(iconWithNewClass);
```