# Show / hide markers leaflet using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have some markers in my map that sometimes are not necessary, I want to implement a checkbox controller that show/hide they. In a few words what I'm trying is adding a class to this markers.

I have a function that create and add to the map the markers.

```
function gateways_markersMap(gateways){
    for (var i = 0; i < gateways.length; i++){
        coo = [gateways[i].gat_lat,gateways[i].gat_lon];

        popUp = "Nombre: " + String(gateways[i].gat_name) + "<br>Id: " + gateways[i].gat_id;

        var iconMarker = new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: '/static/img/markers/yes_fixed-markers/gateway.png',
            iconSize: [35, 35],
            iconAnchor: [12, 41],
            popupAnchor: [1, -34]
        });

        var marker = L.marker(coo, {icon: iconMarker}).bindPopup(popUp);
        $(marker).addClass('prueba'); // HERE I'M TRYING ADD CLASS
        layerGroup.addLayer(marker);
        map.addLayer(layerGroup);
    }
}
```

In other part of my code I have a function that control the checkbox behaviour,

```
function checkboxController(){
    $("#cleanGatewFilter").on('click', function(){
        if ($('#cleanGatewFilter').is(':checked')) {
            $('#allGatewFilter').prop("checked", false);

            $('.prueba').hide() //HERE I WANT TO HIDE THE MARKERS
        }
    });
}
```

But nothing happens.

How can I do this? It is possible to add a class to the markers and then show / hide they with the checkbox?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add a class to a Leaflet marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267411/how-do-you-add-a-class-to-a-leaflet-marker)

Comment: I read it yesterday but no, using `$(marker._icon).addClass('prueba');` I have the same problem. Maybe I'm not understanding what I have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the markers to a featureGroup to show the markers and remove the group from the map to hide the markers.

```
var fg = L.featureGroup();
function gateways_markersMap(gateways){
    for (var i = 0; i < gateways.length; i++){
        coo = [gateways[i].gat_lat,gateways[i].gat_lon];

        popUp = "Nombre: " + String(gateways[i].gat_name) + "<br>Id: " + gateways[i].gat_id;

        var iconMarker = new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: '/static/img/markers/yes_fixed-markers/gateway.png',
            iconSize: [35, 35],
            iconAnchor: [12, 41],
            popupAnchor: [1, -34]
        });

        var marker = L.marker(coo, {icon: iconMarker}).bindPopup(popUp);
        marker.addTo(fg);
    }
    //Add the featuregroup and the layergroup outside of the loop to the map
    layerGroup.addLayer(fg);
    map.addLayer(layerGroup);
}
```

```
function checkboxController(){
    $("#cleanGatewFilter").on('click', function(){
        if ($('#cleanGatewFilter').is(':checked')) {
            $('#allGatewFilter').prop("checked", false);
            layerGroup.removeLayer(fg); //hide
        }else{
            layerGroup.addLayer(fg); //show
        }
    });
}
```